# How do I combine a dynamic collection of Observables into a new Observable?

Tags: .net, parent-child, system.reactive, observablecollection

I have the concept of a `Room` in my program. Each room has a number of `User`s on it, and each user has an `Observable` that states what level of silence he wants in the room. When the user selects a new value, I just push it to the Observable by calling `OnNext` on an internal `BehaviorSubject` instance inside the `User` class.

The main logic in the program is that one should be able to tell "what level of silence" the room needs. For example, if at least one user in the room needs silence, then the entire room needs silence.

This is a simplification of my classes:

First, I'm using an enum to represent the possible sound levels. Right now there is only two values:

```
enum SoundLevelRequirement
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Indicates that the user is ok with any sound level in the room.
    /// </summary>
    None,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Indicates that the user needs absolute silence in the room.
    /// </summary>
    Silence
}
```

The user just exposes an Observable that ticks whenever his status has changed.

```
class User
{
    private readonly BehaviorSubject<SoundLevelRequirement> soundLevel;

    public User(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        soundLevel = new BehaviorSubject<SoundLevelRequirement>(SoundLevelRequirement.None);
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public IObservable<SoundLevelRequirement> SoundLevelChanged => soundLevel.DistinctUntilChanged();

    public void SetSoundLevel(SoundLevelRequirement level)
    {
        soundLevel.OnNext(level);
    }
}
```

And the room class is basically a container for users, and should have it's own observable to represent the overall status of the whole room:

```
class Room
{
    private readonly BehaviorSubject<SoundLevelRequirement> soundLevel;
    private readonly ObservableCollection<User> users;

    public Room(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

        // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO COMBINE ALL CHILD OBSERVABLES INSTEAD 
        // OF USING ANOTHER Subject
        soundLevel = new BehaviorSubject<SoundLevelRequirement>(SoundLevelRequirement.None);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; }

    public IObservable<SoundLevelRequirement> SoundLevel => soundLevel.DistinctUntilChanged();
}
```

I'm having trouble in combining the users `Observable`s using Rx directly into another `Observable`, because of the dynamic nature of the solution. My main problem is that users can leave or join a room at any moment (new `User` objects can be added to or removed from the room), so I don't have a static list of observables to use. If I had a static list, it would be very easy to achieve by leveraging `CombineLatest`, and then doing my filtering logic on it, like this:

```
Users.Select(u => u.SoundLevelChanged).CombineLatest().Select(latest => latest.Max());
```

This way, whenever any user status changes, I just have to see what the "biggest value" is to determine the room's status. But as soon as I add or remove users I need to keep it in sync with the observable, so this does not work.

I also need to make sure to handle whenever users leave the room appropriately. For example, if a room of 5 people is in the "Silence" state due to one user having selected `Silence`, I have to reset the room state when that user leaves and set it back to `None`.

I have thought about using the `ObservableCollection` there to monitor for additions and removals, but I can't come up with something without having to recreate the observable, which obviously will not work since there are people subscribed to the changes already.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to make this simple if you can. You need a simple change to the class `User` to do it.

User needs to add this property:

```
public SoundLevelRequirement SoundLevel => soundLevel.Value;
```

Now you can implement `Room` like this:

```
class Room
{
    private readonly IObservable<SoundLevelRequirement> soundLevel;

    public Room(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

        soundLevel =
            Observable
                .Create<SoundLevelRequirement>(o =>
                    Observable
                        .FromEventPattern<
                            NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler,
                            NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
                            h => this.Users.CollectionChanged += h,
                            h => this.Users.CollectionChanged -= h)
                        .SelectMany(x => this.Users
                            .Select(u => u.SoundLevelChanged
                                .StartWith(u.SoundLevel))
                                .Merge())
                        .Select(ep =>
                            this.Users.Any(u =>
                                u.SoundLevel == SoundLevelRequirement.Silence)
                                    ? SoundLevelRequirement.Silence
                                    : SoundLevelRequirement.None)
                        .DistinctUntilChanged()
                        .Subscribe(o));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; }

    public IObservable<SoundLevelRequirement> SoundLevel => soundLevel.AsObservable();
}
```

If you need to have the `Room.SoundLevel` have a replay of 1 then add in `.Replay(1)` to the `soundLevel` field, but it'll have to become `IConnectableObservable<SoundLevelRequirement>` to make that work. You'll need to then implement `IDisposable` on `Room` to dispose of the connection. This is the right way to do it - you should avoid subjects where possible. They'll just make your code hard to work with.

Comment: This is not what I need. With your code, if a user changes it's level, that will not reflect back in the `Room`s property. I don't want to monitor collection modifications only, but also whenever any of the child's observable changes.

Comment: @julealgon - I've modified my solution. It should work for you now.

Comment: Oh my... that's crazy. I'll test it tomorrow and see how it goes. I was almost giving up on Rx and using a simple polling method. I've been trying to use the ListSubject class along with a special CombineLatest extension method from the Rxx library without success.

Comment: @julealgon - There's almost always a way to do it with Rx, and once you have the query worked out then the code that consumes it is very simple. it's worth persevering.

Comment: I'm trying your solution just now, and it still does not respond to changes on existing users "sometimes". The first thing I did was trying out the solution without the `Replay`, and it only starts working when I remove and readd a user to a room. When I switched to Replay+Connect, it started to display the room status immediately, but then for some reason I can't change the user observable anymore. Perhaps if you could explain your solution a little bit I could figure out the problem on my own. I have to admit that it does not make sense to me.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I can update the user value, and it does seem to work fine with Replay.... this is so frustrating... when I look at the final solution, it just doesn't make sense to me. I really want to hear your explanation now for how this works exactly. Also, I'd really like to avoid having another disposable model, which is caused by replay here. Do you think it would be possible to avoid the `IConnectableObservable` and keep the same results? I also don't like having to expose the value of the `BehaviorSubject`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old but I wanted to point out that using the extension methods in Dynamic Data this can be written in a quite simple way.

The property

```
public SoundLevelRequirement SoundLevel => soundLevel.Value;
```

needs to be added to the `User` class as suggested by `Enigmativity` and then you can simply write

```
    soundLevel = this.Users
        .ToObservableChangeSet()
        .MergeMany(user => user.SoundLevelChanged)
        .Select(_ => this.Users.Select(u => u.SoundLevel).Max());
```

in the constructor of your `Room` class.